# Convert a list of strings to a list of tuples in python

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I have a list of strings in this format:

```
['5,6,7', '8,9,10']
```

I would like to convert this into the format:

```
[(5,6,7), (8,9,10)]
```

So far I have tried this:

```
[tuple(i.split(',')) for i in k]
```

And I obtain:

```
[('5','6','7'), ('8','9','10')]
```

I am a bit stuck on how to simply convert the strings into tuples of integers. Thank you

Comment: Your tuple will contains 3 strings no? ('a','b','c') is already a tuple

Comment: So the variables `a`, `b`, … should be looked up? Or is your question if Python supports atoms? It doesn't.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. You're correct Carlier but I meant to say how would I convert each of the strings inside the tuple into integers?

Comment: By Integers, you mean ascii code of a, b, c... ?

Comment: Once again my mistake, the letters a, b, c are strings of numbers. So I have this: ['5','6','7', '8','9','10']. How would I make this into [(5,6,7), (8,9,10)]. Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: Instead of "strings of numbers" you should use the term "string representation of numbers".

Comment: `map(ast.literal_eval, k)` should do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your strings are strings representation of number, then:

```
[tuple(int(s) for s in i.split(',')) for i in k]
```

Comment: Well, this has been accepted as the answer, but gives [(5,), (6,), (7,), (8,), (9,), (10,)], which is different to what the OP was asking for, so I am now confused, and chances are, other visitors will be too.

Comment: @wookie919 I made the try on my side and it works properly. Are you sure you haven't entered `['1','2','3','4','5','6']` as input?

Comment: @CarlierRobin That's what OP says he has in his comment. Quoting OP's comment: "So I have this: ['5','6','7', '8','9','10']."

Comment: @wookie919 Better ask OP but seeing the question I bet he meant to say ['1,2,3','4,5,6']

Comment: Okay, I have tried to make the original question clear. Carlier is correct and the solution works for integers. Sorry for being confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution is for me the most readable, perhaps it is for others too:

```
a = ['5,6,7', '8,9,10']          # Original list
b = [eval(elem) for elem in a]   # Desired list

print(b)
```

Returns:

`[(5, 6, 7), (8, 9, 10)]`

The key point here being the builtin `eval()` function, which turns each string into a tuple. 
Note though, that this only works if the strings contain numbers, but will fail if given letters as input:

```
eval('dog')

NameError: name 'dog' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question requires the **grouping of elements**. Hence, an appropriate solution would be:

```
l = ['5','6','7', '8','9','10']
[(lambda x: tuple(int(e) for e in x))((i,j,k)) for (i, j, k) in zip(l[0::3], l[1::3], l[2::3])]
```

This outputs:

```
[(5, 6, 7), (8, 9, 10)]
```

As desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
listA = ['21, 3', '13, 4', '15, 7']
# Given list
print("Given list : \n", listA)
# Use split
res = [tuple(map(int, sub.split(', '))) for sub in listA]
# Result
print("List of tuples: \n",res)
```

source: https://homiedevs.com/example/python-convert-list-of-strings-to-list-of-tuples#64288